# cannot get .sql script to run with different server version numbers

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a database/table using SQL. I am running `server version 14.0.1000`.

The `.sql` file is very large but I cannot seem to get it working/create the database on my PC. Some information from the `.sql` file:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.12, for Win64 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: fc
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.23
```

When I run `execute` it says `Query complete with errors`, I run `debug` and I get the following output:

```
Auto-attach to process '[4468] [SQL] DESKTOP-4MI0A88' on machine 'DESKTOP-4MI0A88' succeeded.
The thread 'DESKTOP-4MI0A88\SQLEXPRESS [53]' (0x1404) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[4468] [SQL] DESKTOP-4MI0A88: DESKTOP-4MI0A88\SQLEXPRESS' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The script works on a different machine, could it be a problem with the server version numbers? I am using windows 10.

Comment: This is much more than just a version difference. The script was written for MySql. The database on your machine is Sql Server. Those are two very different database engines. There will be some things in the script that will not be compatible.

Comment: Thanks! I have spent all day on this issue!

Comment: What do you suggest from here? I have tried running it through `mysql workbench` but it just closes when I run it.

Comment: MySql workbench is for connecting to MySql databases; you don't have a MySql database. You need to install a MySql database server on your machine, and remove Sql Server Express if you're not using it for anything else. Remember: these are brand names. It's like trying to put an Chevy engine in a Ford body. Both companies make cars, but you have to stick with parts for that's company's product.